# Why does my SSIS Script Task only partially convert Excel to CSV?

Tags: excel, ssis, export-to-csv

I am trying to convert excels to csv with the script below, it works well on my PC with Visual studio, on the other hand on the server without any errors, it does not take me the whole file the contents of the excel file, I end up with a csv of 12150 lines instead of having around 72400. No error in the event viewer, thank you for your help :

var directory = new DirectoryInfo(SourceFolderPath);
FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.xlsx");

```
        //Declare and initialize variables
        string fileFullPath = "";

        //Get one Book(Excel file at a time)
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            // Chemin d'accès au fichier Excel
            string excelFilePath = file.FullName;

            // Chemin d'accès au fichier CSV
            string filename = file.Name.Replace(".xlsx", "");
            string csvFilePath = DestinationFolderPath + filename + ".csv";

            // Chaîne de connexion OLE DB pour Excel
            string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelFilePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;IMEX = 1\"";

            // Requête SQL pour extraire les données de la feuille de calcul
            string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Journal$]";

            
                // Créez une connexion OLE DB à Excel
                using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    // Exécutez la requête SQL pour extraire les données
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlQuery, connection))
                    {
                        using (DataTable dataTable = new DataTable())
                        {
                            adapter.Fill(dataTable);

                            // Créez un writer pour écrire dans le fichier CSV
                            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(csvFilePath, false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
                            {
                                // Écrivez les en-têtes de colonne dans le fichier CSV
                                foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
                                {
                                    writer.Write(column.ColumnName);
                                    writer.Write(FileDelimited);
                                }
                                writer.WriteLine();

                                // Écrivez les données dans le fichier CSV
                                foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
                                {
                                    foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
                                    {
                                        string valeur = item.ToString().Replace("\n", " - ").Replace("\"", "").Replace("'", "").Replace(";", "-").Replace("|", "-");
                                        writer.Write(valeur);
                                        writer.Write(FileDelimited);
                                    }
                                    writer.WriteLine();
                                }

                              //  writer.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

or if someone has a better idea, with free components, and knowing that in Excel there are line breaks to manage etc...

No error in the event viewer
writer.close
without try/catch to checj job error but no

Comment: Might be interesting to add `bool fireAgain = false;` and `Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "SCR Echo Back",dataTable.Rows.Count, string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);` When you run the package, it should emit in the Information messages a count of the total rows in your data table. And then you can also try wrapping the `foreach (DataRow...` in a try/catch and use the same FireInformation event to pop any errors

Comment: I put exactly the same code in a C# console application, (just change the path), it works, I have the right size.
Due to an ssis configuration? scriptask?

Comment: There's nothing specific to SSIS that would cause that to fail out. If you look at the project type for an SSIS Script Task, it has an Output Type of "Class Library" so what works as a console app would be the same as a class library. A debugging approach could be to add a counter in the Script Task and set a conditional breakpoint when it hits around 12148 lines written. And then just step through the next few loops and see why it's ending early. As to your approach, I've use the ACE OLE drivers as well in SSIS and never had the issue you're encountering.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a data flow task instead of a script task to achieve the same result.

The data flow task would include an `Excel Source`, one or more `Derived Column` tasks to remove unwanted characters and a `Flat File Destination` to produce the CSV output.